# Xamarin Forms ToolbarItem Icon from URL

Tags: image, url, xamarin, xamarin.forms, toolbaritems

I've got a problem: In my Xamarin Forms project I want to show an Icon in the top left corner, but the image is only via url available.

#### This is my Code:

```
var toolbaricon = new ToolbarItem();
toolbaricon.Icon = "urlToImage";
ToolbarItems.Add(toolbaricon);
```

The Item gets added to the ToolbarItems, but doesn't show up.
But if I use a local Image (image from drawable (android)) it works fine.

Is there a solution for this?

Best Regards

Comment: Please consider marking as answer/upvoting if an answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The `ToolBarItem` inherits `MenuItem` which needs a `FileImageSource` as its `Icon` property. This means it only accepts images from the platform resource folder. That means that you can't use an image from a URL.

Comment: But is it possible, to temporary download the image and then assign the source to this downloaded image?

Comment: No because to read it from the file system you need a `StreamImageSource`, which cannot be assigned to a `FileImageSource`.